# What would happen when a transaction fails because "took too long"?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, cpu, time

When call an action of a contract, sometimes meet "Transaction took too long" error.

If a transaction fails because of "took too long" error, the transaction will be discarded in chain? Or next BP will try this transaction again?

Comment: Transaction took too long will make the transaction failure, it will not send to other nodes anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The failed transaction will not be attempted again automatically. If you're the dApp owner, you should increase the CPU resources or wait for them to replete and try again.

Or better yet, redesign the dApp to make it more efficient if possible.